# New Endpoint-URL for Web2Case in Sandbox

Tags: web2case

The endpoint-URL for Web2Case will changes to web2case.salesforce.com - but what is the new enpoint-URL for web2case in the sanbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this [KNOWLEDGE ARTICLE](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000004389&type=1) from Salesforce.

For example, if your sandbox instance is CS1, your URL should look like this:

```
<form action="https://cs1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

**KNOWLEDGE ARTICLE:** 
Why are Cases not generated from my Web-to-Case form in Sandbox?

**Description:** 
Why are Cases not generated from my Web-to-Case form in Sandbox?

**Resolution:** 
Web-to-Case functionality can be tested in the Sandbox environment.

In order for Cases to be created through a web-to-case form in Sandbox, you must first modify the HTML code generated through:

*Setup | App Setup | Customize | Self-Service | Web-to-Case.*

As generated by setup from within Sandbox, the form POST line reads:

```
<form action="http://test.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

You must substitute "test" in the above line with your sandbox instance name (cs1, cs2, cs3 etc).

For example, if your sandbox instance is CS1, you must change this code to read:

```
<form action="https://cs1.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
```

If this does not resolve the issue, check if there are multiple case record types in the org, and make sure you add the following to the code:

```
<input type=hidden name="recordType" id="recordType" value="012xxxxxxxxxx">
```